# Выполнение клиентской функции на стороне сервера

Tags: node.js, canvas, javascript

Добрый день.

Такая ситуация:

Нужно выполнить клиентскую *функцию** на стороне сервера (Node.js). Думаю, выход один - socket.io. Но дело в том, что выполнять эту функции нужно даже тогда, когда клиент не подключился к серверу. Следовательно отправив сокет на клиента, он к нему не придет и следовательно клиент не отправит результат функции.

* *функция measureText*

* *Значение measureText должно храниться именно на сервере.*

Был вариант такой:

Отправляем сокет, если клиентов нет, то запоминаем отправку сокета. Как только к серверу подключается первый клиент, то отправляем сокет, который мы запомнили.
Это, конечно, работает, но, сами понимаете, - это костыль.

Если другие варианты? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

*Это костыль*

А идея - не костыль? :)
Пишите для клиента одну, а для сервера другую функцию - так проще. А отслеживать события, которые инициируют выполнение - куда проще.